# Trying to exit from a program is not working

Tags: python-3.x, function

I'm currently teaching myself python from books, YouTube, etc. Recently, I've started from [Python Tutorial - Python for Beginners [Full Course]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uQrJ0TkZlc). I've been trying to make some bigger programs by myself (learning from python documentation) than the ones in this video. Hence, this is my question:

I'm trying to find a solution for how to exit from a function `the_func` after pressing keys `(n, q ,e)`. Unfortunately, after choosing an option to not try again, the loop is still running. This is the output copied from the terminal:

```
Guess the secret number: 1
Guess the secret number: 2
Guess the secret number: 3
Sorry, you are loser!
------------------------- 

Would you tray again? Y/N
 y
Guess the secret number: 9
The secret number was 9.
You are won!
------------------------- 

Would you tray again? Y/N
 n
Thank you!
Guess the secret number:
```

You can see that even after choosing `n`, it's starting again.

This is the code:

```
# Guessing Game

def the_func() :
    
    again = 'Would you tray again? Y/N'
    scecret_number = 9
    guess_count = 0
    guess_limit = 3


    while guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = int(input("Guess the secret number: "))
        guess_count += 1
        
        if guess == scecret_number:
            print(f"The secret number was {scecret_number}.\nYou are won!")
            break

    else:
        print("Sorry, you are loser!")


    print("-" * int(len(again)), "\n")
    print(again)

    answer = input(" ")

    while True:
        if answer.lower() == "y":
            the_func()
            
        #elif answer.lower() == "n":
        if answer.lower() in {'n', 'q', 'e'}:
            print("Thank you!")
            
            #return
            break
#         else:
#             print("Sorry, that was an invalid command!")

    the_func()

the_func()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is known as [Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). In simple words, the function is getting called repeatedly at the end of it. Here's the example that might clear it more to you:

```py
def foo()
    while True:
        print('xyz')
        break
    foo() # Calling the function at the end causes recursion, i.e., infinite looping of the function (unless 'it is returned before the call')
foo()
```

You might ask, what is the solution?
As said above, you can prevent infinite recursion of a function (if you want to), by implicit returning the function using [return](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/).

Your answer is present in your code only. Let me show you where:

```py
while True:
    if answer.lower() == "y":
        the_func()
            
#elif answer.lower() == "n":
    if answer.lower() in {'n', 'q', 'e'}: # I would use 'elif' here, if the above 'if' statement did not have the calling of the same function. But, here, using 'if' or 'elif' doesn't matter really.
        print("Thank you!")       
        return
#break
#else:
#print("Sorry, that was an invalid command!")
```

I hope you understood what you are doing wrong, and if you have any doubts, just add a comment and I would help as fast as I can.

Answer (score 0):

**Haaa.. DONE, So what we need**

```
while True: 
    if answer.lower() == "y": 
        return the_func() ***# <= add return to the_func()***
        
    if answer.lower() in {'n', 'q', 'quit', 'e', 'exit'}: 
        print("Thank you!")
        return
        
    #the_func() #<== mark as comment, and func not will bee looped again the_func()
    
the_func()
```

However, @Alex thank you!